# Test users that are friends don't show up as friends in app

Tags: testing

I'm using Unity.

I have 2 test users, they are friends ( I checked by logging in as them).
I made them friends using the user interface in the Test users section of the app.

I login as test user 1 in my Unity application.
I create a "invite friends" dialog.
The problem is that the test user 2 is not visible in the friend list, only a bunch of [Friend 001], [Friend 002] entries.

If I login with my real FB  account I do see my real friends.

Anyone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The AppRequest system doesn't work with test accounts. This is why you see it work fine with your real account.